# Troubles to extract informations from a specific list of files

Tags: powershell

I have some troubles with a script I need to create. I will explain context :

- I have loads of folders where loads of xml files are located and I need to extract specific informations from this file, each `vox` file used and specified in these links.
  I'm able to do it by using this command :

  `dir d:\masc\xml -I *.xml -R | Select-String vox</prompt> | select Line > test3.txt`

Where `"d:\masc\xml"` is the location of all folders, the select-string command allows me to extract each line I need, and the final select allows me to extract the list to a txt file by keeping only content and not informations about file and line number. This works fine.

- On the other side I have a `csv` file which contains list of file. Indeed the complete list of files is about 2000 xml file, and I only need to extract informations from a specific list which is in this csv file.

I used an `import-csv` command to import it, and piped it with a foreach-object to loop it, but I cannot find how to combinate with my dir command:

```
$File = "D:\MASC\TableauXML.csv"
Import-Csv $File | Foreach-Object { 
foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties)
{
    dir d:\masc\xml -I *.xml -R | Select-String vox</prompt> | select Line > test3.txt
} 
}
```

If I add a `temp` variable in the foreach-object loop to confirm that all `csv` content is well imported it works fine, as example :

```
$FileToCheck = $_.PSObject.Properties | % {$_.name}
```

Does anybody can say me how I have to do? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can't see what do you need to do?

Comment: I'm trying to extract informations from a specific list of files located in a specific directory where are stored loads of files.
I'm able to extract informations from all files (first command), I'm able to load my csv file where all files I need to scan are listed, but I'm not able to combinate both... :-/ Hope i'm more clear :)

Comment: Is it more clear? Do you have any idea ? :)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear. Try to give an example of data (strings) from file and example of result that you need instead of code that you wrote.